# How did Black Panther have enough funds in dollars?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

At the end of the *Black Panther* movie, T'Challa was shown to buy lots of buildings in US like it was nothing to him.

I can understand that universal valuation of Wakanda can make Black Panther the richest man on Earth if he owns Wakanda. But, how did he get funds in actual dollars when Wakanda doesn't trade with the outside world?

Comment: I think you may have missed the entire point of the end of the movie.

Comment: @KutuluMike Enlighten me..

Comment: T'Challa chose to start trading with the outside world, plus the US government now knows Wakanda has tons of Vibranium to buy.

Comment: @KutuluMike That UN scene came later and T'Challa just announced about the trade. It gets proved by the fact that a guy even casted a doubt after the announcement..

Comment: @KutuluMike And not just vibranium, but *advanced technologies* based on it.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that Wakanda doesn't trade with the outside world does not mean it is not able to get Currency but the film itself indicates how he had these funds available.

Wakandians are known to operate in the wider world as undercover Spies, Operatives, Agents etc. In order for these Wakandians to be able to survive you can imagine that Shell Corporations and offshore bank accounts etc have been set up to provide funds, it would not be hard to appropriate these funds for other purposes in this same way you can imagine that Wakanda has used its resources over the years to prevent its secrets being discovered.

The film is not about Wakanda becoming involved in the wider world, it is about Wakanda being open and its involvement no longer being secretive.

Answer (score 2):

Bouncing off of @RichardC 's excellent answer, there is the possibility that Wakanda has been *clandestinely* trading with the world for some time. The comics establish that [Quinjets](http://marvel.com/universe/Quinjet) include technology from Wakanda. It is plausible that the equivalent MCU vehicles do too. It is possible that Quinjet tech was sold to the outside world through shell companies that concealed the true origins of the tech. I imagine it could be similar to how North Korea or Iran are able to buy and sell around sanctions and blockades, or how some organized crime and terror groups can "launder" funds coming in and out and seemingly function without obvious channels.

More mundanely, some of the overseas operatives could be working regular jobs in their host countries and sending portions of their incomes "back home" in the form of cash or cash equivalents. This is, in fact, a common practice in our own world, though mostly done electronically nowadays. We can see in *Black Panther* that Wakanda has cloaking devices, so how do we know that large quantities of US dollars, Euros, Yen, and other hard currencies are not being discretely exported (or smuggled out) weekly?